# Yii2 multiple pjax reload takes too long

Tags: ajax, yii2, pjax

I have to refresh multiple areas on same page for which I have used pjax and its working fine, the only thing is that its taking too long. Is there any way I can speed it up ?? I am refreshing pjax blocks on ajax response as below:

```
$.pjax.reload({container: "#div1", async:false});
$.pjax.reload({container: "#div2", async:false});
```

Comment: you surely would have to wait for every request to complete as you are using `async: false`

Comment: Is there any alternate solution for this ? @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: apparently you have no other chice than removing async option, maybe someone else can auggest any alternatives other than this

Comment: What data are you getting via ajax? What is driving the reloads? Maybe you can optimise your database query/schema or request less fields in the data? Or get smaller paginated chunks for each load/reload request? If you want a meaningful answer you will need to provide more information on the bigger picture of what you are working with.

Comment: I am trying to update user profile. After updating profile I am getting the response of success/failed via ajax. On success response I have to refresh username on 
 different places of same page via pjax eg: dashboard/index, sidepanel, header etc.